# Web scraping selenium to get quizz questions : next button only works for 2 times / 87times

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape this page : https://mlapshin.com/index.php/scrum-quizzes/sm-learning-mode/
I want to scrape the questions and answers
However, I'm having trouble clicking on the next button to scrape all the informations. I've tried doing this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Ihnhn/Documents/WebScrap/Selenium/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://mlapshin.com/index.php/scrum-quizzes/sm-learning-mode/") 
driver.maximize_window()
start_quizz = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='startQuiz']"))).click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,400);") 

all_questions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("wpProQuiz_listItem")
for i in all_questions:
    nom_question = i.find_element_by_class_name("wpProQuiz_question_text").text
    print(nom_question)
    check_answer = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='check']"))).click()
    next_answer = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='next']"))).click()
```

So i wanted to try first, to get just the name of the questions but it gives me TimeoutException
it just scrap the 2 first questions and thats all, so in the second question, it just doesnt click on the button "check" so that I can continue

(there are 87 questions : so I imagined that with this code it would get the 87 questions)

Im am a beginner in web scraping, so Im a litte lost... if anyone could help me
Thanks

Comment: you use absolute xpath `//input[@name='check']` so it always searchs first input `Check` on page but every question has own input with the same name - and when it displays second question then your xpath waits for `Check` in first question. You should use relative xpath

Answer (score 0):

You use absolute xpath `"//input[@name='check']"` so it always searchs first `input Check` on page but if you check HTML in browser then you see every question has own `input Check` (and `input Next`) - and when it displays second question then your `xpath` waits for `input Check` in first question - but this input is hidden and it can't be `clickable`.

You should use relative xpath (with dot) `".//input[@name='check']"` and you should use `i` instead of `driver` when you use relative xpath.

```
all_questions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("wpProQuiz_listItem")
for i in all_questions:

    # relative to `i`
    nom_question = i.find_element_by_class_name("wpProQuiz_question_text").text
    print(nom_question)

    # relative to `i`
    check_answer = WebDriverWait(i, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,".//input[@name='check']"))).click()

    # relative to `i`
    next_answer = WebDriverWait(i, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,".//input[@name='next']"))).click()
```

---

Full working code which I used to test it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
#import time

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://mlapshin.com/index.php/scrum-quizzes/sm-learning-mode/") 
driver.maximize_window()

start_quizz = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='startQuiz']"))).click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,400);") 

all_questions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("wpProQuiz_listItem")

for item in all_questions:
    
    # relative to `item`
    nom_question = item.find_element_by_class_name("wpProQuiz_question_text").text
    print(nom_question)
    
    # relative to `item`
    check_answer = WebDriverWait(item, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,".//input[@name='check']"))).click()
    #time.sleep(0.5)
    
    # relative to `item`
    next_answer = WebDriverWait(item, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='next']"))).click()
    #time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: if you have new problem then you should create new question on new page - and you will have new place for code and explanations.